# Why am I getting IllegalArgumentException error while deleting data by id by Retrofit2? And how to fix it?

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit2

I am trying to delete an user in phpmyadmin by id parameter by Java, Retrofit, PHP, MySQL. When I press the delete button, in the Logcat I am getting this **ERROR**:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "id={id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
    for method UsersAPI.deletePost
```

**UserAPI.java** :

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.DELETE;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface UsersAPI {

    @GET("users_read.php")
    Call<List<User>> getUsers();

    @DELETE("delete_user.php?id={id}")
    Call<Void> deletePost(@Path("id") int id);
}
```

**AdminActivity.java** : Here is the listener for delete button:

```
btnDeleteUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int deleteId = Integer.parseInt(editTextDeleteUser.getText().toString());
                Call<Void> call = usersAPI.deletePost(deleteId);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                        Toast.makeText(AdminActivity.this,"Response code: "+response.code(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(AdminActivity.this, "Error : "+ t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            });
```

Why am I getting this error? And How to fix it. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
 @DELETE("delete_user.php?id={id}")
Call<Void> deletePost(@Path("id") int id);
```

With this

```
 @DELETE("delete_user.php")
Call<Void> deletePost(@Query("id") int id);
```

@Path is used for building a dynamic endpoint, but for Query's you need to query annotation.